# Command of CMD,Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#

I have a problem with the code  Launcher  to game. All comes down to a few lines of code, it's exactly the command cmd.exe ,I encountered with error

```
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object".
```

I do not know how to solve this because I wrote here that I have no idea, and my knowledge is limited. Line string argument "Start".

**Code :**

```
public string nn;
this.nn = Name;

string newlok = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()+"\\"+nn;
string TempFilePath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() +"\\"+ System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name+".exe"; 


private void UpdateApplication(string tempFilePath1,string newlok)
{
   here there is a problem --->    string argument = "/C  Start \"\" /D \"{0}\" \"{1}\"& choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 4 & Del /F /Q \"{2}\" & choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 4";

                ProcessStartInfo Info = new ProcessStartInfo();
                Info.Arguments = String.Format(argument, Path.GetDirectoryName(newlok.ToString()) + "\\", Path.GetFileName(newlok.ToString()), tempFilePath1);
                Info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
                Info.CreateNoWindow = true;
                Info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                Process.Start(Info);
}
```

OK, now some explanation.

Name is taken from XML, all is read because I checked, returns `Programs.exe` and probably the rest catch on :D

Maybe for some little vaguely explained but my language English regrets...

Comment: When does the exception occur? can you include the full stack trace?

Comment: When you are done checking the Update, the code here I did not give, but only the part that perhaps has to do with the problem

Comment: What is `lokali`, and is it null? Which line of code **exactly** is the error thrown on? (The exception should give you a line number)

Comment: Sorry ,I forgot change this,but it does not work.Is string newlok.returns properly or "Program.exe".

Comment: Can I suggest that you try a string literal for argument (argument = @"/c ... etc?

Comment: Can you be slightly more specific that "it does not work"?

Comment: Okay, I've just put your example into a console app and it compiles and runs file (I obviously didn't go as far as deleting anything), and I had to reconcile the various compile errors (as others have already pointed out lokali doesn't exist, also, you seem to have some code outside of a function that should be inside.

Comment: Yes lokali doesn't exits .. lokali was converted on string newlok ,but still the same error

Answer (score 1):

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

This error happens when you try to use a property or call a method of an object that is null.

A simple use of Visual studio DEBUGGER can tell you the object because of which it is happening. Just look at the stack trace and put a debugger on that line. Check the objects of that line and see if any one is null and you are trying to use that objects property. Handle the same.